# nginx returns 502 when using nodejs with express and socket.io

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I can not figure out the problem. Maybe someone can help me.
I have a node.js application that is based on express.js and also uses socket.io. This application runs behind an nginx proxy and until today everything worked without any problem.
Today i had to restart the server and since then I always get a 502 when I try to access the site.

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

upstream <my_app> {
    server <my_ip>:4567;
    keepalive 512;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <my_domain>;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 32M;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
    large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/<my_app>_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/<my_app>_error.log;

    location ~ ^/(favicon.ico) {
        root /var/www/<my_app_root>/public;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_next_upstream     error timeout       http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy       true;

        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade             $http_upgrade;


        proxy_buffers           8                   32k;
        proxy_buffer_size       64k;

        proxy_pass              http://<my_app>;
        proxy_redirect          off;
    }
}
```

this is the error from nginx

```
2014/05/09 13:53:38 [error] 3093#0: *23 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 217.110.45.3, server: <my_domain>, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://<my_ip>:4567/", host: "<my_domain>"
```

I use nginx version 1.6.0 on ubuntu 12.04

this is the script that starts the app in /etc/init.d/:

```
#!/bin/bash

NODE_ENV="production"
NODE_APP="<my_app>.js"
APP_DIR="/var/www/<my_domain>"
PID_FILE=/<my_path_to_pid>/app.pid
LOG_FILE=/<my_path_to_log>/app.log
NODE_EXEC="supervisor -w /var/www/<my_domain>"

start_app (){
    if [ -f $PID_FILE ]
    then
        echo "$PID_FILE exists, App is already running or crashed"
    else
        echo "Starting App ..."
        NODE_ENV=$NODE_ENV $NODE_EXEC $APP_DIR/$NODE_APP  1>$LOG_FILE 2>&1 &
        echo $! > $PID_FILE;
    fi
}

stop_app (){
    if [ ! -f $PID_FILE ]
    then
        echo "$PID_FILE does not exist, App is not running"
    else
        echo "Stopping $APP_DIR/$NODE_APP ..."
        echo "Killing `cat $PID_FILE`"
        kill `cat $PID_FILE`;
        rm -f $PID_FILE;
        echo "App stopped"
    fi
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start_app
    ;;

    stop)
        stop_app
    ;;

    restart)
        stop_app
        start_app
    ;;

    status)
        if [ -f $PID_FILE ]
        then
            PID=`cat $PID_FILE`
            if [ -z "`ps -ef | grep $PID | grep -v grep`" ]
            then
                echo "Node app stopped but pid file exists"
            else
                echo "Node app running with pid $PID"

            fi
        else
            echo "Node app stopped"
        fi
    ;;

    *)
        echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/node-app {start|stop|restart|status}"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Is it possible that you forgot to create an init script for your Node application and you forgot to start it?

Comment: I have an init script. Maybe there is something wrong there. I'll add it to my question.

Comment: Questions that come to mind. 1. Is your Node app actually visible in the process table? 2. How do you ensure that it runs on port 4567? 3. What happens if port 4567 is already in use?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: I have no idea, what happened there, but after a few hours, the site was available again. very weird.

Comment: Better check the app logfile you defined above, it may contain more clues about the outage...